# Do I have to wait for 30 minutes when a on-demand Dynamodb table is throttled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using `on-demand` Dynamodb table and I have read the doc https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/on-demand-table-throttling-dynamodb/. It says `You might experience throttling if you exceed double your previous traffic peak within 30 minutes`. It means Dynamodb adjust the RCU/WCU based on the last 30 minutes.

Let's say my table is throttled, do I have to wait for maximum 30 minutes until the table adjust its RCU/WCU? Or does the table update RCU immediately? or in a few minutes?

The reason I am asking is that I'd like to put a retry on my application code to retry the DB action whenever there is a throttle. How can I add sleep interval between the retry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacity is always managed with an On Demand table to support double any previous peak throughput, but if you grow faster than that, the table will add physical capacity (physical partitions).

When DynamoDB adds partitions it can take between 5 minutes and 30 minutes for that capacity to be available for use.

It has nothing to do with RCUs/WCUs because On Demand tables don't have capacity units.

Note: You may stay throttled if you've designed a hot partition key in either the base table or a GSI.

During the throttle period requests are still getting handled (and handled at a good rate). Just like if you see a line at the grocery store check out, you get in line. Don't design the code to come back in 30 minutes hoping there's no line after adding checkers. The grocery store will be "adding checkers" when it notices the load is high, but it also keeps the existing work processing.

Comment: so that means the worse case is the throttling may last 30 minutes if the traffic stays the same?

Comment: Scaling DynamoDB is a deep topic. Some access patterns can’t be resolved by adding capacity.